# Automatically generated test data to a DB from a schema?

Tags: postgresql, database, test-data

I have [a discussion-db](http://varlena.com/GeneralBits/110.php), and I need a great amount of test data, for different sized samples. Please, see the [ready SELECT, JOIN and CREATE-queries, please scroll down in the link.](http://varlena.com/GeneralBits/110.php)

1. How can I automatically generate test data to the db?
2. How to generate test data in different sized samples?
3. Is there some ready tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are a couple of suggestions for free tools that generate test data:

- [Databene Benerator](http://databene.org/): supports many JDBC-capable database brands, uses XML format compatible with DbUnit, GPL license.
- [Super Smack](http://vegan.net/tony/supersmack/): originally a load-test tool for MySQL, it also supports PostgreSQL and it includes a generator of mock data.

  - A current version of Super Smack appears to be [available here](https://github.com/winebarrel/super-smack)

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591892/tools-for-generating-mock-data) here on StackOverflow in February, and the two choices above seemed like the best options.

Comment: Which one is easier to use for Postgres?

Comment: As a software developer, you should have the ability to download two such tools, try them out, and evaluate which one meets your needs best.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is super dated, but I was looking for the answer to this exact question today and I came across this:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Sample_Databases

Out of the options listed (including built in tools like pgbench), pgFoundry has several compelling options that works perfectly for the test cases I am working on.

I thought it might help someone like me, so there it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get automatically generated data and insert it into the database (I'm sure you could pull it off with a python script or something), but if you're just looking for endless blabbering to stick into a db, [this](http://www.lipsum.com/) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a postres person, but in many other DBs I've used, a simple mechanism for generating large quantities of test data is a cross join. The technique is particularly useful for generating large quantities of test data.

Here's a [nice blog post on it](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/02/06/60490.aspx) (SQL Server specific though).