# Python: Which modules for a discussion site?

Tags: python, postgresql, module, web

A site should be ready in 6 days. I am not allowed to use any framework such as Django. I am going to use:

**Python modules**

1. HTMLGen to generate HTML code from class-based description
2. SQLObject, relational tables onto Python's class model
3. ?

**Other**

3. Python 2.5
4. [A variant of the Postgres schema](http://varlena.com/GeneralBits/110.php)
5. [Super Smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295641/automatically-generated-test-data-to-a-db-from-a-schema) for testing the schema

**Which modules would you use in the limited time?**

**Plan**

1. To generate class model with SQLOject from the [schema](http://varlena.com/GeneralBits/110.php)
2. then generate HTML code from the gererated class model with HTMLGen. (changed to Jinja2)
3. ?

Comment: Six days and no frameworks?  Yikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Jinja for templating? It will be much faster than working with autogenerated html.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2/2.0

Comment: So I replace HTMLGen with Jinja2 if it is faster. +1 Ready examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/) started out as a project to collect best-of-breed packages together with some glue code to stitch them together.  I think the latest incarnation uses Pylons, but perhaps only for the controller.  At the very least, you can see the [TurboGears Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbogears) to see what components they selected (see the subsections [TurboGears 1.x components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbogears#TurboGears_1.x_components) and [TurboGears 2.x components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbogears#TurboGears_2.x_components)), since they've obviously had some experience with this kind of thing.  There's nothing "discussion" specific, but really you just want a templating library, a database library or ORM, a WSGI implementation with a router/controller and perhaps some AJAXy or other presentation widgets.