# Mock Object Data

Tags: c#, mocking, test-data, lorem-ipsum

I'd like to mock up object data, not the objects themselves.  In other words, I would like to generate a collection of n objects and pass it into a function which generates random data strings and numbers.  Is there anything to do this?  Think of it as a [Lorem Ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) for object data.  Constraints around numerical ranges etc. are not necessary, but would be a bonus.

Comment: This looks (almost) like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591892/tools-for-generating-mock-data.

Comment: @Jeremy Those are for databases.  I'm looking for solutiosn related to pure objects.

Comment: True, but some of the answers in that thread create objects before going to the DB. I thought there was enough overlap that it worth pointing out without flagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I thought of when I read your question was QuickCheck, a testing tool for Haskell.  In QuickCheck you specify properties (invariants) that your function should have, and you can specify valid ranges for inputs (plus a bunch more features), and QuickCheck will generate a bunch of random input data and throw it at your function and check too see if the output matches the specification.  Nosing around a little I found out there is an F# port of it so QuickCheck exists in the .net world:

http://fscheck.codeplex.com/

There is also a MS Research project Pex that might be close to what you are thinking of:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Pex/

"...Pex finds interesting input-output values of your methods, which you can save as a small test suite with high code coverage. Microsoft Pex is a Visual Studio add-in for testing .NET Framework applications."

I haven't used it before, but it looked like it is good for generating edge case data that exercises any and all branches of a function.  It actually analyzes a function rather than just throwing truly random stuff at it.

Answer (score 4):

There also appears to be a .NET port of the Ruby `Faker` gem, which gets a lot of use for rigging fake data objects in Ruby. I haven't used it, but it might be worth looking into:

https://github.com/slashdotdash/faker-cs

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that no one has mentioned [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture) yet:

```
[TestMethod]
public void IntroductoryTest()
{
    // Fixture setup
    Fixture fixture = new Fixture();

    int expectedNumber = fixture.CreateAnonymous<int>();
    MyClass sut = fixture.CreateAnonymous<MyClass>();
    // Exercise system
    int result = sut.Echo(expectedNumber);
    // Verify outcome
    Assert.AreEqual<int>(expectedNumber, result, "Echo");
    // Teardown
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could setup an `ObjectRandomizer` class that takes an array of objects, uses reflection to examine the object for private members, and then use reflection to set a random value for that member.  This works only if you don't care what the random data looks like per object.

Alternatively, you could build a set of classes for each data object that generates random data for them.  This might work well if you didn't want to include the random generation methods inside the actual assemblies.  For example, if you had a `Person` class, you could have a `PersonRandomizer` class in a test assembly.  In your test class (or in a `Randomizer` class), You could then use reflection to find a type `PersonRandomizer`, and if it exists, call `PersonRandomizer.Randomize(Person p)`.

If you go with yahya's suggestion, I suggest creating an interface `IRandomizable` for objects that support randomization OR marking them with a new attribute `Randomizable` that you can detect at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

For my testing I just add a method to all the classes I create that does this and call it randomize. Each class knows what the legal data for an object of that class should look like. After creating the object simply call its randomize method to populate it with random mock up data. You could also add specialized methods to generate random data strings or numbers based on constraints and these specialized methods can be shared across all your classes.

Comment: I thought about doing this on a base class and using reflection to generate adaquate data, but I'd like something that already exists and can be plugged in.  Maybe this is something I should create.