# unit testing in memory - sql server

Tags: .net, sql-server, unit-testing, connection-string

I have an application that connect to an SQL Server database. The database is configured with a connectionString.

I have some unit tests, everything works fine. But it connect to my real database (by reading the connectionString) and my tests populate this database. I do not want that, I rather prefer to connect to an in-memory database, to have no impact on my database.

Does it exist a solution for that? How can I configured my connectionString for tests?

Regards.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a look at [Stubbing / mocking a database in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550128/stubbing-mocking-a-database-in-net)

Comment: Can you just use a separate database?

Comment: Yes I can, it is what I do now. But I rather prefer not have to maintain another database.