# Fill your tables with junk data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am lazy, sometimes excruciatingly lazy but hey (ironically) this is how we get stuff done right?

Had a simple idea that may or not be out there. If it is I would like to know and if not perhaps I will make it.

When working with my MSSQL database sometimes I want to test the performance of various transactions over tables and view and procedures etc... Does anyone know if there is a way to fill a table up with `x` rows of junk data mearly to experiment with.

One could simple enough..

```
INSERT INTO `[TABLE]`
SELECT `COLUMNS` FROM [`SOURCE_TABLE`]
```

Or do some kind of...

```
DECLARE count int 
SET count = 0

WHILE count <= `x`
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `[TABLE]`
(...column list...)
VALUES
(...VALUES (could include the count here as a primary key))

SET count = count + 1
END
```

But it seems like there is or should already be something out there. Any ideas??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for Generating Mock Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591892/tools-for-generating-mock-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Data Generation Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833237%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (a feature of Visual Studio database projects).

Answer (score 3):

I use redgate 
[SQL Data generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/)

Comment: I've used this as well. It's very nice, and can cover most situations if you're actually looking for halfway decent data, too. The problem of course is that $300 price tag.

Comment: $300 is cheap. You would spend much more than that in hours of development time to do the same thing.

Comment: @HLGEM, it is sad but true that many people work on a fixed salary for cheap companies that don't care how long you have to work to get the job done.  you'd be more likely to get blood from a stone than get that software at some of the companies I've worked for in the past.

Comment: I upvoted this but declared the Data Generation Plan as the winner because it is built it. What do you all think about this decision?

Answer (score 1):

[WinSQL](http://www.synametrics.com/SynametricsWebApp/WinSQL.jsp) seems to have a data generator (which I did not test) and has a free version. But the Test data generation wizard seems to be reserved to the Pro version.

Answer (score 1):

My personal favorite would be to generate a CSV file (using a 4.5 lines script) and load it into your SQL DB using [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx). This will also allow better customization of the data as sometimes is needed (e.g. when writing tests).