# Populating database with additional data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, populate

I have a relatively small (MySQL) database with ~50 tables which takes about 100 MB of disk space. For my tests I would like to increase the size of the data to 100-1000 GB keeping the same schema (tables, keys, indexes). What would be the best way/tool to populate this database    with additional data (pseudorandom with respect to existing data) ?

Hopefully the question makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for Generating Mock Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591892/tools-for-generating-mock-data)

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to build php program that would connect to mysql and loop on insert to insert dummy data into the database

like

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES ('Peter', 'Griffin',35)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt this program that fetches fake data from the internet and populate tables (provided that the columns it has will fit your needs). Check it out [here](https://github.com/adriano-pinaffo/populate_data) if you want.

[image]